# If statement with multiple logical operator not working

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
    function calculateAmount(val) {
    var quantity = val;
    if (quantity <= 100 && quantity < 1000){
    var divobj = document.getElementById('discount');
    divobj.value = 4;
    var divobj1 = document.getElementById('yousaved');
    var yousaved = 0.4 * quantity;
    divobj1.value = yousaved;
    }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for=“quantity”>:</label>
<input type="quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity" aria-describedby="quantityHelp" placeholder="100 to 1000000" onchange="calculateAmount(this.value)" required>
<small id="quantityHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Any amount between 100 to 1000000.</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for=“discount”>discount in %:</label>
<input type="discount" readonly class="form-control" id="discount" placeholder="Interest">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for=“yousaved”>Total saving:</label>
<input type="yousaved" readonly class="form-control" id="yousaved" placeholder="Your Savings">
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

`if (quantity <= 100 && quantity < 1000)` condition not working, the only value accepted and get calculated is 100, and even var addition and multiplication is not working eg: `quantity - quantity * 4/100`

Comment: It really makes no sense to have both conditions on same if, because a number greater than 100 wil always return false on first condition and will never be tested against the second one cause the logical operator is AND (&&).

Comment: per @Triby is this a typo? should `<=` really be `>=` ? i.e `greater than or equal to 100 and less than 100`

Comment: @Bibberty, yes, it's a typo, cause the help text says "between 100 and 1000".

Comment: Actually, it has further conditions such as quantity >= 1000 && quantity < 10000, quantity >= 10000 && quantity < 100000, and for each range the discount percentage will differ

Answer (score 0):

Based on text from your HTML (Number between 100 and 1000), the script should be:

```
<script>
function calculateAmount(val) {
    var quantity = val;
    if (quantity >= 100 && quantity <= 1000){
        var divobj = document.getElementById('discount');
        divobj.value = 4;
        var divobj1 = document.getElementById('yousaved');
        var yousaved = 0.4 * quantity;
        divobj1.value = yousaved;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, just a typo. 
Probably better to just delete this question Arunkumar.

```js
function calculateAmount(val) {
  var quantity = val;
  if (quantity >= 100 && quantity < 1000) {
    var divobj = document.getElementById('discount');
    divobj.value = 4;
    var divobj1 = document.getElementById('yousaved');
    var yousaved = 0.4 * quantity;
    divobj1.value = yousaved;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for=“quantity”>:</label>
    <input type="quantity" class="form-control" id="quantity" aria-describedby="quantityHelp" placeholder="100 to 1000000" onchange="calculateAmount(this.value)" required>
    <small id="quantityHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Any amount between 100 to 1000000.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for=“discount”>discount in %:</label>
    <input type="discount" readonly class="form-control" id="discount" placeholder="Interest">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for=“yousaved”>Total saving:</label>
    <input type="yousaved" readonly class="form-control" id="yousaved" placeholder="Your Savings">
  </div>
</form>
```